# How to pre-populate data in Swift?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, realm

I'm having an issue trying to store a bunch of items with properties in my app. What I have already tried (and mostly works) is making my custom class:

```
class Waterz {

var entitle: String? = nil
var artitle: String? = nil
var isFavorited: Bool? = nil
var date: [String]? = nil
var frequency: [daysOfWeek]? = nil
var subMenus: Array<Waterz>? = nil
var content: String? = nil
var location: String? = nil
var audio: [(String, reciterNames)]? = nil

init() {
}

convenience init(entitle: String, artitle: String, isFavorited: Bool?, date: [String]?, frequency: [daysOfWeek]?, content: String?, location: String?, audio: [(String, reciterNames)]?) {
    self.init()
    ...
}

}
```

and then I made another class where I have my database:

```
class WaterzBank {

// all
var allItems: [Waterz]
var allDuas: [Waterz]
var allAmal: [Waterz]

// main categories
var mainCategories: Waterz

// individual categories
    var duaKumayl: Waterz
    var duaMakarem: Waterz
    var duaNudba: Waterz

... (like 5 thousand more)
}

// Initialize them here
init() {
    duaKumayl = Waterz(entitle: "Dua Kumayl", artitle: "دعاء كميل", isFavorited: false, date: ["1-27"], frequency: [.sunday], content: "kumayl", location: nil, audio: nil)
    duaMakarem = Waterz(entitle: "Dua Makarem Al-Akhlaaq", artitle: "دعاء مكارم الأخلاق", isFavorited: true, date: ["1-27"], frequency: [.sunday, .everyday], content: "duaMakaremAlAkhlaaq", location: nil, audio: nil)
    duaNudba = Waterz(entitle: "Dua Nudba", artitle: "دعاء النّدبة", isFavorited: true, date: nil, frequency: nil,  content: "duaNudba", location: nil, audio: nil)

    ...(initializing all the other variables)

    favorites = Waterz(entitle: "Favorites", artitle: "المفضلة", subMenus: allItems.filter {
        $0.isFavorited == true
    })


    // MARK: - Main

    mainCategories = Waterz(entitle: "Categories", artitle: "الأقسام", subMenus: [duas, amal, ziyarat, munajat, taqeebat, others, favorites])
}
```

Everything works with this setup, except permanently changing the status of the items being favorited (by the user, everything starts off as unfavorited, but I want them to be able to change that). I tried so many ways such as using direct Realm, JSON parsing to Realm, CoreData, UserDefaults, but none of it worked out for me.

So everything starts off as unfavorited. When the user tries to favorite one of them. It does work, but when they close the app and reopen it, it reverts to unfavorited.

The only thing the user should be able to change is the 'isFavorited' property. Everything else, I set and it comes with the app as soon as you download it.

What should I do in this case? Do I have to completely change my system? Is there a way to parse all of my initialized variables into a Realm Database? If so, will I be able to parse things like `audio`, which is of type `[(String, Enum.type)]`? This is my first app and I'm really confused. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the error? Try `var isFavorited: Bool? = false`

Comment: Declaring all properties of you custom object as optionals is not encouraged. Declare optional only the properties that might not have a value. Btw you should use a struct which will not require you to create a custom initializer

Comment: Try to create a verifiable example and update your question.

Comment: I don't understand what the `Waterz` class is supposed to be in this context, is it a fixed set of immutable instances or is the user supposed to modify them and/or create new ones and if so do you want to save the new and changed objects?

Comment: You've tagged this question with Realm but there's nothing in that code that has anything to do with Realm. i.e. Your classes would need to be defined as Object and the properties would need to the defined as `@objc dynamic var` to be managed by Realm. Did you work through the Realm [Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)? Also, what you're asking is unclear - what does *didn't work out for me* mean exactly? Is there an error? Does something not work?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The user is unable to permanently change the 'favorited' status of a variable. The user should just be able to change that.

Comment: As for why I tagged Realm, it's because I wanted to see if that's what I'm looking for. I tried two ways of making my database with Realm: 1) Used the Realm Studio app for making my class and variables. The issue with this is that I can't use the type [(String, Enum.type)] in Realm, and I also am unable to change the 'subMenus' from the app after I've created the variable (not just 'subMenus', but any array). 2) JSON parsing. This had the same issue. I can't use the type [(String, Enum.type)] and I also can't have custom types like 'Waterz'.

Comment: You can very easily change the isFavored property in a Realm object. What's causing it to not work? In this case the `Waterz` class isn't a Realm object so you can change it whenever you like. Using Realm Studio is not a good option for making a database; define your Realm Classes in code, populate them with data and write them to Realm. What are you trying to do with this `[(String, Enum.type)] `? As long as your enums are mapped to privatives/supported types, you can do that as well. Lastly you can definitely have custom 'types' like 'Waterz' but to be clear, that's a **class** not a *type*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I "populate them with data and write them to Realm?" Is there a way to do this using just Swift? Like without using the Realm Studio or JSON.

Comment: Yes; Realm offers full Swift support and you can create, write and manage Realm objects with Swift. In fact, there's an entire [Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) with Swift examples of how to work with Realm. If you want to create a pre-populated Realm to include with your project you *could* do that within Realm Studio but IMO it would be much quicker to build and app that creates it for you and then drag the Realm into your project You could also generate that Realm when an app is first installed on first App launch. See the starting guide for more info.

Comment: Thank you. How would I move my initialized variables into Realm directly without rewriting everything?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a Realm object, populate it with data and store it in Realm?

Comment: Yes, but like in a similar way to how I made my own databank using a class.

Comment: Here's what you need to do; go through the Realm getting started guide I linked above. Write some code using Realm objects to gain an understanding how Realm works. Maybe even make a small To Do app where you can add, edit and delete To Do's. When you get stuck on that, post a specific and detailed question about where you're stuck. My guess is that once you've done that, you'll be able to answer you own question! Give that a shot.